# Limit rows returned using TableAdapter (typed DataSets)

Tags: .net, sql, tableadapter, rowcount

Does anyone know the best way to limit the number of rows returned when using typed TableAdapters?  Options appear to be:

1. Pass "top X" as a parameter (can't do this until we're on SQLS2008
2. Issue a dynamic SQL statement: `set rowcount X` before calling my tableadapter method, then `set rowcount 0` aftwards.
3. Something else I haven't thought of :).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TOP n, but you have to put brackets around it like so:

```
SELECT TOP (100) * FROM ...
```

You can also parameterise it as follows:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 100
SELECT TOP (@count) * FROM field_company
```

Comment: If you can update this to make the value 100 parameterised, you can have a point :P

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@count) FLD1, FLD2 FROM mytable WITH (nolock)
```

The parameter is generated along with any others in the TableAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this using parameterized stored procedure.

```
create procedure dbo.spFoo 
    @NoOfRows int = 200

AS


declare @sql varchar(2000)
select @sql =
'select top ' + Cast(@NoOfRows as varchar) + ' * FROM   Foo'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not going to use stored procedures, unfortunately.  Also, are you sure you can parameterise the value for "TOP" in SQL Server 2005, even in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way.

You can't parameterise the "TOP" value, but you **can** parameterise the "SET ROWCOUNT X" value.

Therefore, this works:

```
create procedure test_SelectTopFromTable (@rowCount int) as
begin
    set rowcount @rowCount
    select * from table
    set rowcount 0
end

exec test_SelectTopFromTable 100
```

However I do need to deal with exceptions happening, which would prevent the `set rowcount 0` statement from running.  I'll keep digging.

**UPDATE**
My boss told me the way to make it work (and it's so simple I'm a bit embarrassed) but I'm going to get him to post his answer rather than make it look like I found it myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

TableadApter use SqlDataAdapter, which **already has this feature**.

What to do:

Click on **Fill()** or **FillByXXX()** method

```
myTradesTableAdapter.Fill(...)
```

and **press F12** - it will bring you to its **source code** generated by designer.
**Copy** this method.

Go to the DataSet designer, click on **table adapter** and press **F7** - it will **create/open code** for the TableAdapters namespace.

**Paste Fill() method** here and **modify** it some like in example below:

```
namespace MyApp.DsMyDataTableAdapters {

public partial class MyTradesTableAdapter
{
    //// copy-paste method from generated Fill()
    //// and make new name: Fill() ==> FillTop()
    //// use the same params and add new one: int topN
    public virtual int FillTop(             //
         DsMyData.MyTradesDataTable dataTable,
         int someParameterId,
         // ...
         int topN)  // add new param
    {
        // original code:
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = someParameterId;

        if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true))
        {
            dataTable.Clear();
        }


        // modified code
        int returnValue = 0;
        if (topN > 0)                  // validate topN
        {
            // get topN rows
            returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(0, topN, dataTable);   

        }
        else 
        {
            // get all rows (original code) in case topN = 0 or negative
            returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    // ....
}
```

and then you can **use it** as:

```
int somePrm = 123;
myTradesTableAdapter.Fill(ds.myTradesTable, somePrm) // original - get all rows
myTradesTableAdapter.FillTop(ds.myTradesTable, somePrm, 100) // new - get 100 rows
```